# Why is this code in PROLOG using constraints gives Operator expected syntax error?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

```
col_tri(Vars):- Vars=[X1,X2,X3],
                Vars in 1..3,
                X1#\=X2,
                X1#\=X3,
                X2#\=X3,
                label(Vars).
```

This code is giving me this error in line 2 (Vars in 1..3,):
ERROR: c:/users/xxxx/desktop/prolog/tp2.pl:2:20: Syntax error: Operator expected

Comment: `Vars ins 1..3`

Comment: and `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` to get access to `in` and `ins` operators. SWI doesn't load them automatically.

Comment: Cool, then I have turned it into a proper answer and filled in some explanation, if you want to green tick accept it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators are things like the `+` in `1 + 1`, and in your code the `in` in `Vars in 1..3`.

Prolog code can define new operators at runtime.

The `in` operator is not a standard part of Prolog, it's defined by the CLPFD library, which SWI Prolog has, but does not load automatically.

And `in` is for a single variable on the left, there is also `ins` for a list of variables like your `Vars`. So the code should become:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

col_tri(Vars):- Vars=[X1,X2,X3],
                Vars ins 1..3,
                X1#\=X2,
                X1#\=X3,
                X2#\=X3,
                label(Vars).
```